# failed to run Microsoft face api in C#

Tags: vb.net-to-c#

I am trying to implement **Microsoft Face API in C#** using code available on GitHub.

I followed all the steps given in :

[Microsoft Face API: Windows Client Library & Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-face-windows)

I have some errors like:

**1-** The name "`SampleScenarios`" does not exist in the namespace `"clr-namespace:SampleUserControlLibrary;assembly=SampleUserControlLibrary"`.

**2-** The type '`sampleUtil:SampleScenarios`' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

**3-** The tag '`SampleScenarios`' does not exist in XML namespace '`clr-namespace:SampleUserControlLibrary;assembly=SampleUserControlLibrary`'. Line 8 Position 10.

In Solution Explorer, "`SampleUserControlLibrary (Load fail)`" appears: that means no user controls libraries are loaded.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: visual studio 2015